# How should I go about updating a Stateless Widget when it's reloaded?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a JSON file to store a list that I want to display and update. I have one StatefulWidget(called "HOME") that shows the list using a ListView.builder. I also have a StatefulWidget(called "ADD") that adds an object to the list and updates the JSON file. When I finish adding the list a Navigate back to "HOME", I receive this error:
[image: Error Upon Returning to HOME]

[image]

HOME:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  PlayerList playerList;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readPlayerData().then((PlayerList list) {
      playerList = list;
    });

    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // add Player to the PlayerList
    void addPlayer() async {
      await Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPlayer()),
      );

      initState();
    }

    void removePlayer(int index) async {

      playerList.players.removeAt(index);
      await writePlayerData(playerList);
    }

    playerList = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Smash Tracker'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {addPlayer();},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.grey[900],
            shadowColor: Colors.black87,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: playerList.players.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  //leading: characterIcons(playerList.players[index]),
                  title: Text(
                    playerList.players[index].playerId,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    playerList.players[index].playerSetCount,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/playerCard', arguments: {
                      'player': playerList.players[index],
                      'playerList': playerList,
                      'index': index
                    });
                  },
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      removePlayer(index);
                      PlayerList newPlayerList = await readPlayerData();
                      setState(()  {
                        playerList = newPlayerList;
                      });
                      },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

The code used to save a new Object when the 'Save' button is pressed
ADD:

```
  void _saveForm() async {
      
      PlayerList playerList = await readPlayerData();

      Player newPlayer = new Player("${playerName.trim()}", "0 - 0",
          new Characters(_myChar1Result, _myChar2Result), "");
      playerList.players.add(newPlayer);

      await writePlayerData(playerList);

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
      );
  }
```

I think the error occurs when the ListView.builder attemps to call on the playerList object. I'm not sure. I'll be happy to provide any additional information.

'Edit:'Here is the readPlayerData() including the methods it relies on:

```
Future<PlayerList> readPlayerData () async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    final jsonResponse = (jsonDecode(contents)); //wrap in encode
    PlayerList playerList = PlayerList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    return playerList;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return getPlayerList(); //just loads a placeholder json in the assets folder;
  }

Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  print(path);
  return File('$path/playerData.json');
}
```

The json file saves the way I want it to.

Comment: Can you show me your `readPlayerData()`? Your doubt is indeed right. It is while building the list only. So the main game is in `Home`, not `Add`. But be sure to check also, whether the `Player` data is getting added to the list correctly. And why are you using `pushReplacement()` and not `pushAndRemoveUntil()`?

Comment: In the meantime, could you please answer this question: `And why are you using pushReplacement() and not pushAndRemoveUntil()`? Also, **be sure to check also, whether the Player data is getting added to the list correctly.**

Comment: I'm pretty new to Flutter development, so I'll try that instead. I have the code print out the JSON file after I add it to make sure it's updated.

Comment: It is okay Ayrock618, that is why we come here to seek help! Can you try using `pushAndRemoveUntil()` on both the places, that is `Home` and `Add`?  Also, do give a read on [pushAndRemoveUntil<T>](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

Comment: @D.R. `Navigator.pop()` will not help rebuild the widget and show the new updated value. The page needs to have new data which is being done in `init()`. Here `pushAndRemoveUntil()` would be helpful. Or if he wants to use `Navigator.pop()` with some value returned, then we need to use [ValueListenableBuiler<T>](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html), which will listen to the new value every time, we return some data, and pass it to the `playerList`, in order for `ListView.builder` to show the updated data which is in this case is 2 much

Comment: I changed "Home" to use pushAndRemoveUntil() and "Add" to use pop(). Now I don't get the error, but I get a black screen

Comment: No no, use `pushAndRemoveUntil` in `ADD` too, in place of `Navigator.pushReplacement()`.

Comment: Oh.. ok. I misread that.\

Comment: **BOTH THE PLACES, HOME as well as ADD**

Comment: Do I need to use the await keyword in front of the Navigator. I apologize about all of the question. You have been the most help while I've been working on this project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218594/discussion-between-alok-and-ayrock618).

Comment: my point is use of `provider` &  `notifyListners` is so helpful in this kind of situation, when one needs some stuff in too many location and changing that stuff at any point.

Comment: But if you are suggesting something, then please be specific, cos he has just started off with `Flutter`, and cannot understand `Navigator.pop()` usage clearly. I hope I am making sense to you @D.R.

Comment: No problem dear,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were multiple problems in your code, and this is how I fixed it.

**SOLUTION** I will give you the solution file wise, so follow along

**1. HOME**

- Moving out the methods => `addPlayer()` and `removePlayer()`
- Adding `setState((){})` for `playerList` in `initState()`
- Removing this line completely, `playerList = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`. Too buggy to use to this line
- Right usage of `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()` in `addPlayer()`

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  PlayerList playerList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readPlayerData().then((PlayerList list) {
      setState(() => playerList = list);
    });
  }

  // add Player to the PlayerList
  void addPlayer() async {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPlayer()),
        (_) => false);

    //initState();
  }

  void removePlayer(int index) async {
    playerList.players.removeAt(index);
    await writePlayerData(playerList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // copy paste your Scaffold content here
    // rest everything will be same
    // NO layerList = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

**2. ADD**

- Importing of the Characters Modal was wrong, and conflicting. It should be imported like `import 'package:smash_tracker/models/character_model.dart' as Characters;`
- Then while passing the Object, it should be passed like this `new Characters.Characters(_myChar1Result, _myChar2Result)`
- Correct usage of `Navigator.pushAndReplaceUntil()`
- Removing this line inside Widget{} `PlayerList playerList = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`
- Rest will be same

```
import 'package:smash_tracker/models/character_model.dart' as Characters;

void _saveForm() async {
    setState(() {
      _myChar1Result = _myChar1;
      _myChar2Result = _myChar2;
    });

    PlayerList playerList = await readPlayerData();

    Player newPlayer = new Player("${playerName.trim()}", "0 - 0",
        new Characters.Characters(_myChar1Result, _myChar2Result), "");
    playerList.players.add(newPlayer);

    print('added new Player');
    await writePlayerData(playerList);
    print('updated JSON');

    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home())
        (_) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // no more PlayerList playerList = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold();
  }
```

After testing the app, it works like the below.

[image: Result GIF]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!!!

Comment: Pleasure is all mine. All the very best @Ayrock618 :)